# Window.prompt() not working from the background script of MS-Edge Extension

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, browser-extension

I m trying to invoke the Window.prompt() from the background script of a browser extension that I created for MS-Edge. 
I m using Microsoft Edge 41.

I tried out a Window.alert() from the same background scrip. It's working fine  and is opening an alert box in the browser window.

This is working fine;

```
Window.alert("This is a sample alert");
```

But, THIS IS NOT;

```
var val = Window.prompt("Enter Some Random Value");
```

Comment: I try to test it with MS Edge and I am able to produce the issue. I am able to display the alert but Edge is not showing the prompt from JS script of Edge extension. It can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is Edge default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. If I get any solution or a work around than I will try to provide you in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This seems like a bug to me too. Have been breaking my head over this for quite some time now.

Comment: I had already provided the feedback for this issue via internal feedback channel. I will try to inform you if I get any update on this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.prompt("Enter Some Random Value")
```

it tried with small `w` and it is working on my end.

Comment: I already tried it out, no luck. Even without the window object it should work,ideally.

Comment: Which version of Edge re you using? Are you sure that you re trying this out from a browser extension Backround Script?